# Select and display named elements of an array in a JSON column

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

In Azure SQL I have a table, "violation", with a JSON column, "course_json" that contains an array.  An example is:

```
[{
    "course_int": "1465",
    "course_key": "LEND1254",
    "course_name": "Mortgage Servicing Introduction",
    "test_int": "0"
}, {
    "course_int": "1464",
    "course_key": "LEND1211",
    "course_name": "Mortgage Servicing Transfer",
    "test_int": "0"
}]
```

I would like to select rows in the violation table and display columns of the table and the "course_key" as:

```
LEND12654,LEND1211
```

If there were always a fixed number of course_key's I could use:

```
select person_id,event_date, JSON_VALUE(course_json, '$[0].course_key') + ',' + JSON_VALUE(course_json, '$[1].course_key')  from violation
```

But they aren't fixed... there may be one, two, ten... I'll never know.

So, is it possible to iterate through all the course_keys and display them all in a comma separated format?

Comment: Return the data as a set, not as scalar values, and then string aggregate.

Comment: Will have to look up how to do that.  Guessing that's json_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `JSON_VALUE`, use `OPENJSON` to get all the courses and `STRING_AGG` to build the course_key delimited list.

```
SELECT
      person_id
    , event_date
    , (SELECT STRING_AGG(course_key,',')
       FROM OPENJSON(course_json)
       WITH (
           course_key nvarchar(MAX) '$.course_key'
      )) AS course_key
FROM dbo.violation;
```

| person_id | event_date | course_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-21 | LEND1254,LEND1211 |

Comment: Awesome!  Put it into a  subquery and it's exactly what I needed